# Laravel 5.0 delayed execution

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-messaging

I need to delay execution of one method in Laravel 5.0, or to be more specific, I need it to be executed at special given time. The method is sending notification through GCM to mobile app, and I need to do it repeatedly and set it to a different time. As I found out, there is no way how to intentionally delay notification in GCM. I know basics from working with cron and scheduling in Laravel, but I cant find answer to my problem.

The method I need to execute with delay is this:

```
public function pushAndroid($receiver, $message, $data)
{

    $pushManager = new PushManager(PushManager::ENVIRONMENT_DEV);

    $gcmAdapter = new GcmAdapter(array(
            'apiKey' => self::GCM_API_KEY
    ));

    $androidDevicesArray = array(new Device($receiver));

    $devices = new DeviceCollection($androidDevicesArray);

    $msg = new GcmMessage($message, $data);

    $push = new Push($gcmAdapter, $devices, $msg);
        $pushManager->add($push);
        $pushManager->push(); 

}
```

Information when (date+time) it should be executed is stored in table in database. And for every notification, I need to do it only once, not repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling you can setup something that fits your needs.

Make something with the looks of

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   // Here you get the collection for the current date and time
   $notifications = YourModel::whereDate('datecolumn',\Carbon\Carbon::now());
   ...
})->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Queues with Delayed Dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#delayed-dispatching), if this makes more sense. Since you hinted you only need to do it once.

```
ProcessJobClassName::dispatch($podcast)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```